# DSC pull schedule randomly stops working

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dsc

I am using DSC to configure 30 servers.

They are configured to pull with **ApplyAndAutoCorrect**.

This generally works great, but randomly, servers will stop all DSC activity.  The servers never attempt to pull configuration again.

The only way I can resolve the issue is by re-configuring the LocalConfigurationManager, but this gets tedious.

Does anyone know how I can troubleshoot this?

**Update**

**Update-DscConfiguration -Wait -Verbose** runs as expected.  The issue is that it doesn't run automatically.  I am checking this by looking in the operational event log.

**Get-DscLocalConfigurationManager Output:**

`ActionAfterReboot              : ContinueConfiguration
AgentId                        : 9F0D574A-C0F5-11E6-80CA-005056B8643D
AllowModuleOverWrite           : True
CertificateID                  :
ConfigurationDownloadManagers  : {}
ConfigurationID                : 64e35e72-6f65-4f44-9b5f-915bfe9d157a
ConfigurationMode              : ApplyAndAutoCorrect
ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins : 15
Credential                     :
DebugMode                      : {NONE}
DownloadManagerCustomData      : {MSFT_KeyValuePair (key = "ServerUrl"), MSFT_KeyValuePair (key =
                                 "AllowUnsecureConnection")}
DownloadManagerName            : WebDownloadManager
LCMCompatibleVersions          : {1.0, 2.0}
LCMState                       : Busy
LCMStateDetail                 : LCM is checking and applying new available configuration on pull server.
LCMVersion                     : 2.0
StatusRetentionTimeInDays      : 10
PartialConfigurations          :
RebootNodeIfNeeded             : False
RefreshFrequencyMins           : 30
RefreshMode                    : Pull
ReportManagers                 : {}
ResourceModuleManagers         : {}
PSComputerName                 :`

All servers are running WMF 5

Comment: Does `Update-DscConfiguration -wait` on those faulty servers work?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf - Updated the main question

Answer (score 0):

if 'Update-DscConfiguration -wait -verbose' is not pulling down the configuration, it is mostly due to the fact that the node already has up to date configuration. 
DSC not running consistency regularly is mysterious. Can you paste the output of Get-DscLocalConfigurationManager?
Which version of WMF are you using?

Comment: I have added an update to the main post